# Spring Roo: how can I code a customized search page based on several backing entities?

Tags: java, spring-roo

As we know, Roo will create a list pages for every entity. Suppose I have 3 domain classes - Company, Dept. and Employee, I want to display the detail info in a customized list page, which will contain the fields from all of the 3 classes, how can I code?
I used the 'web mvc controller' in Roo shell, but I have no idea what should be the next step.

The version of Roo is 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Roo does not generate finders across multiple entities automatically. Auto generated finders can only work on fields of a single entity.

The way to get customized list page would be to write a custom finder (either in the domain or in the service layer) to include all the fields/entities you require.

Custom-list = custom controller + custom finder + custom view

Verified with Roo 1.2.2

A Spring team member suggested the following in an [older thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84828-Tip-how-to-generate-multi-field-finders): "*Your best bet is to generate as much of the finder as you can using Roo, then push it in and modify it to include the other fields you want to query.*"

Comment: You are right! But I used another approach - 'web mvc controller', and implemented my custom finder method in controller class - the method is copied/modified from another controller's list() method.